# Segue transition from top to bottom in Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift

I need help with custom segue transition from top to bottom. Its easy transition but I don't know how to do it. Is it done in a storyboard or must I do it in code? If it must do programmatically how I do it?

Comment: What kind of transition? Push segue? Modal segue? What?

Comment: Sorry I am not experienced in Swift and I learning now. Tolerace little bit and calm mood, please. I think it is not appropriate to have this ugly attitude. I need push segue.

Comment: Please don't tell me how to ask for more info. You've given the info, that's good, and it's enough.

Comment: ...welcome to stack overflow...please try to explain the problem as clearly as possible so we may help you. Also, please don't go undermining the members of this community, especially if you're asking for its help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to write a *custom transition animation* for a push segue. So this is what you are going to do:

- Set a delegate for your navigation controller.
- In the delegate, implement `func navigationController(_ navigationController: UINavigationController, animationControllerFor operation: UINavigationControllerOperation, from fromVC: UIViewController, to toVC: UIViewController) -> UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning?` to return an object implementing UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning (this is often `self` in real life)
- In that object, implement `func transitionDuration(using ctx: UIViewControllerContextTransitioning?) -> TimeInterval` and `func animateTransition(using ctx: UIViewControllerContextTransitioning)`.
- In `animateTransition`, get the info from the context (`ctx`). Put the `to` view into the `containerView` and animate it to its `finalFrame`. In your case, you'll start with the view above the final frame and animate it downwards, as you've specified. When you are all done (i.e. in the animation's completion handler), be sure to call `completeTransition` on the context.